# Laptop with two on-board ethernet 10/100 ports that also supports Red Hat 5.5

Tags: laptop, ethernet, dual-connections

Is there a laptop that has two on-board ethernet 10/100 ports that also supports Red Hat 5.5

Comment: I doubt you'll find a laptop with two on-board LAN ports, and I really don't see many reasons why you would need that on a laptop, but for those few instances you do, you can always add a second one via USB or PCMCIA.

Comment: Red Hat 5.5? RHEL 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you need exactly, but if you cant find a laptop like this, you can:

- You can use a single Ethernet port that is configured two VLANs that is connected to a small smart switch that breaks those VLANs out to two physical ports.
- Use any linux supported USB/Expresscard Ethernet dongle.

Another option is to virtualize the RH 5.5 install inside a Linux host that supports more drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use any laptop with a single ethernet port and which supports RedHat 5.5. Then add a PCMCIA Ethernet card (about $10).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to get an [ExpressCard Ethernet adapter](http://www.google.co.uk/products?hl=en-GB&rlz=1T4GGLL_en-GBGB392AE393&q=expresscard+ethernet&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=SH7PTJnLHI2OjAfS1OjOBg&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=1&ved=0CC4QrQQwAA) which would allow you to use just about any laptop that has Linux support.